# Trim text in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
https://videows1.douyucdn.cn/live/high_12350844720190721092508-upload-f6cd/0704ae76898440f99c6e738c687d413a_0000000.ts?k=db7c96ce8829f45a9b473a453c73dd8a&t=15d4b829f&nlimit=5&u=275209677&ct=web&vid=10201331&pt=2&cdn=ws&d=6c1ede202b60f1196d299eb100091501
```

I want to trim this URL in 3 rows in Google sheet like that

A1:

```
https://videows1.douyucdn.cn/live/high_12350844720190721092508-upload-f6cd/0704ae76898440f99c6e738c687d413a
```

A2:

```
_0000000.ts
```

A3:

```
?k=db7c96ce8829f45a9b473a453c73dd8a&t=15d4b829f&nlimit=5&u=275209677&ct=web&vid=10201331&pt=2&cdn=ws&d=6c1ede202b60f1196d299eb100091501
```

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Presumably this is something that can be repeated at will with other URL. So what are delimiters to identify each section?

Answer (score 0):

cell **A1:**

```
=LEFT(INDEX(SPLIT(A6, "?"),,1),LEN(INDEX(SPLIT(A6, "?"),,1))-11)
```

cell **A2:**

```
=RIGHT(INDEX(SPLIT(A6, "?"),,1), 11)
```

cell **A3:**

```
="?"&INDEX(SPLIT(A6, "?"),,2)
```

---

**all in one:**

```
={LEFT(INDEX(SPLIT(A6, "?"),,1),LEN(INDEX(SPLIT(A6, "?"),,1))-11);
  RIGHT(INDEX(SPLIT(A6, "?"),,1), 11);
  "?"&INDEX(SPLIT(A6, "?"),,2)}
```

[image: 0]